# What is the services.msc file in Windows?

Tags: windows

Why does Windows need *services.msc* registry?

The programs can be loaded dynamically from system32, right?

When does this registry come into the picture?

Comment: What is meant by "registry"? Something related to [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)? Or some kind of registration process? E.g., registration of DLL files/software components?

Comment: The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*), but perhaps somebody else can come up with qualified guess?

Comment: From *[Microsoft Management Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console)*: *"Snap-ins are registered in the [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]\{CLSID} and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MMC\Snapins] registry keys."*

Answer (score 5):

It's the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) file that loads the Services snap-in.  It's used to administer Windows services.  It provides a GUI to do things like:

- Start / stop / disable services
- Change login contexts for services
- Set auto actions for service failures

Computer Management also loads up this snap-in (start it from Control Panel or right-click on Computer and choose Manage).

Comment: mmc meant for ? these services are automatically loaded by the os ?

Comment: Yes.  MMC stands for Microsoft Management Console and is a standard interface for administering Windows components and layered products.  The services here are processing running in the background.  Same basic concept as *nix daemons.

Comment: Here services.msc the extention is .msc . what is the extention for this? I read that windows will recognize only .bat , .exe files to be executablen . Then how .msc file is able to execute here ?

Comment: Windows has another mechanism that will open files with recognized extensions by opening the application associated with that extension.  It's not exactly executing the .msc file, it's launching MMC and opening the .msc file in it.

Comment: @user2720323: windows uses a file type association to know what program to open the file in by extension. its the same idea as double clicking a .doc file and having the document open in MS Word. .msc files open using the program mmc.exe